# Send signals through headphone cable

Tags: android, headphones

I've done quite a bit of searching on this but haven't found anything.

I have an idea for an app to control a device, that would need to connect through the headphone cable.

Is it possible to send signals through the headphone socket?

Answer (score 0):

Arbitrary data can be played out audio jack using [`Media Player`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/index.html#playraw) with a raw resource.  The signal would be limited by the bandwidth of the particular device, for example between 20 Hz and 16 KHz.

Comment: So would it be possible to control a slr camera like this? I.E my Canon uses a 2.5mm jack for the remote shutter

Answer (score 0):

use AudioManager

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html

Then you can setWiredHeadsetOn(true) or if it won't work play with setMode